# SQL - new column shall retrieve value from a different column&row based on a condition in another column

Tags: sql

I have the following table

| Reg_Nr | Class | Grade | Test |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1585 | A | 5.8 |  |
| 1588 | B | 5.81 |  |
| 1590 | C | 5.87 |  |
| 1600 | D | 5.98 |  |
| 1645 | AA | 6.09 |  |
| 1648 | BB | 6.10 |  |
| 1650 | CC | 6.17 |  |
| 1660 | DD | 6.27 |  |

For column Test I want to use a Column level formula that will take the following conditions

- if the reg_nr is 1585 it will return the value of Grade from 1585 divided by grade from 1645; if the reg_nr value is 1588, it will return the value of Grade from 1588 divided by grade from 1648.

any suggestions?

I tried creating a separate column to store on the same row the value that the grade has to be divided by but am having troubles returning a value from a different row and column.
Ex: I know that if Reg_Nr is 1585 I have to look up the 1645 Req_Nr and return the Grade from that row.

Comment: What is the logic that determins the Grade to use - or is it explicitely just those two specific situations? Are you looking to update the table or just a query? Sounds like you just need a case expression.

Comment: The grade is actually a sum of couple other columns.
I have 14 scenarios and do not expect the number to grow. (i just posted some of them as example. A using AA, B using BB and so on)
looking to update the table by adding an extra column (see the empty one called: Test). In this column I will use the Grade values. (would divide them and get the results)

can you give me an example of the case expression you have in mind? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what the rest would look like

But for the pattern you provided, so if you wanted also 1645 to have a text the reg_Nr must have Class AAAA

```
SELECT
t1."Reg_Nr", t1."Class", t1."Grade", t1."Grade" / t2."Grade"
FROM test1 t1 LEFT JOIN test1 t2 ON t2."Class" = t1."Class" || t1."Class"
ORDEr BY t1."Reg_Nr"
```

| Reg_Nr | Class | Grade | ?column? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1585 | A | 5.80 | 0.95238095238095238095 |
| 1588 | B | 5.81 | 0.95245901639344262295 |
| 1590 | C | 5.87 | 0.95137763371150729335 |
| 1600 | D | 5.98 | 0.95374800637958532695 |
| 1645 | AA | 6.09 | *null* |
| 1648 | BB | 6.10 | *null* |
| 1650 | CC | 6.17 | *null* |
| 1660 | DD | 6.27 | *null* |

> ```
> SELECT 8
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3gy618RE)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the calculation on all rows without needing a join:

```
select *,
    case when Reg_Nr in (1585, 1588) then
        min(case when Reg_Nr in (1585, 1588) then Grade end) over () /    
        min(case when Reg_Nr in (1645, 1648) then Grade end) over ()
    end as Test
from test1
order by Reg_Nr;
```